# Javascript DOM Manipulation working on local machine, but not on localhost

Tags: javascript, express, dom, localhost, hosting

Hey I am new to coding and trying to piece together what I have learnt so far. I am now trying to put JS DOM Manipulation and express together by changing a 'Drum Kit' project from a local machine project to a localhost using express. I have successfully loaded the page with HTML, and CSS inside a 'public' folder. However, the JS which gives my buttons behaviour is no longer working even though I did not change the  which still resides inside the project root folder. How can I make it work?

For clarity, I have:
2 .js files:

index.js - contains pure js &
app.js - contains express for localhost

1 index.html file &
1 package.json &
1 public folder with 'css', 'images', 'sounds' subfolders.

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Drum Kit</title>
  <!-- Changed href to reflect root path from 'public' folder -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>
  </div>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>    
<footer>
  Made with ❤️.
</footer>
```

My app.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();


app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})


app.listen(3000, (req, res) => {
    console.log("The server is now listening on Port 3000!")
})
```

My index.js code (which I am trying to get to run through a script tag in the html. works when viewing local file path through chrome, but doesn't when I combine with express on localhost)

```
var buttonArray = document.querySelectorAll("button.drum");

//Detecting Button press
for (i = 0; i < buttonArray.length; i++) {
  buttonArray[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    checkButtonPressed(buttonInnerHTML);
    buttonAnimation(buttonInnerHTML);
  });
}

//Detecting keyboard press
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
  var buttonPressed = evt.key;
  checkButtonPressed(buttonPressed);
  buttonAnimation(buttonPressed);
});

//Function to check what button was pressed and play the respective sounds
function checkButtonPressed(key) {
  switch (key) {
    case "w":
      var crash = new Audio("sounds/crash.mp3");
      crash.play();

      break;
    case "a":
      var kickBass = new Audio("sounds/kick-bass.mp3");
      kickBass.play();

      break;
    case "s":
      var tom1 = new Audio("sounds/tom-1.mp3");
      tom1.play();

      break;
    case "d":
      var tom2 = new Audio("sounds/tom-2.mp3");
      tom2.play();

      break;
    case "j":
      var tom3 = new Audio("sounds/tom-3.mp3");
      tom3.play();

      break;
    case "k":
      var tom4 = new Audio("sounds/tom-4.mp3");
      tom4.play();

      break;
    case "l":
      var snare = new Audio("sounds/snare.mp3");
      snare.play();

      break;

    default:
      console.log(key);
      break;
  }
}

//Function to check what button or key was pressed and change the style

function buttonAnimation(currentKey) {
  var activeButton  = document.querySelector("." + currentKey);
  activeButton .classList.add("pressed");
  setTimeout(function () {
    activeButton .classList.remove("pressed");
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Can you change app.use(express.static("public")); to app.use(express.static(__dirname+"public"));

Comment: @GrantHerman `const path = require('path'); app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));`. `path.join` should be used

Comment: hey thanks for replying, but none of those solves my issue. I'm trying to get an index.js file in the project root folder which contains the javascript to add event listeners and sounds upon key presses but I can't seem to find a way to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it by creating a 'js' folder in the 'public' folder where express serves up static files, then transferring the index.js file inside. Linking to the file just requires a little bit of a tweak as 'public' folder is now the root folder.

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

I figure this means that whatever .js files that are meant to provide behaviour to the HTML is considered a static file as well, and as long as used with express, is to be treated similarly to images, css or sounds.